# How to take input for all the elements of a 2d string at one shot?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, user-input

I want to store data in a 2d string. The conventional way would be :

```
char arr[20][20];
int i;
int size;
scanf("%d",&size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
 scanf("%s", arr[i]);
```

This way I would have input:

```
Hey
I 
Am
New
Here
```

I want to have input as : Hey I am new here
and the array should have : `a[20][20]={"Hey","I","am","new","here"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most elegant way of achieving this will be,

1. Read the input using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. Tokenize using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)
3. Store the tokens in the array elements, after validity checking.

This way, you have many advantages, like

- If at all using a fixed sized-array, you can  get rid of the issue for a separate user input for `size`. You can only keep on tokenizing the whole input till the array elements are there.
- Perform the validity checking of the input values (using `strlen()`, maybe)
- You can have the flexibility of not having a pre-determined sized array and using dynamic-memory allocation, you can allocate and resize the *array*, based on the number (and size) of inputs, (if you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.
Strangely though scanf worked too, maybe coz it doesnt read space, so it stored the next word in the following index. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnot matter for `scanf()` whether you use '\n'(keyboard key-enter) or spaces to separate the input it will work the same way.The standard defined is that any whitespace can separate ino

That is,if you take input as-

```
Hey
I 
Am
New
Here
```

or as-

```
 Hey I am new here
```

it will always store them as {"Hey","I","am","new","here"}